# Need help with this .tbl file

Tags: binary, strings

I don't know if it's encrypted, but I tried changing encoding to latin1, but no avail, some text are still not clear, file looks to be like a csv table. Plus, it has a FTABLE as a header, I don't know what that means. Any insight will be very much appreciated.

The file starts with `FTABLE`, several null bytes and then:

```
46 54 41 42 4C 45 00 00 00 00 10 00 4A 02 00 00
08 00 00 00 20 02 00 00 48 0B 00 00 51 0B 00 00
22 00 00 00 25 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 43 52 45 41
```

... `CREA` (43 52 45 41) which in text form continues to form the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `c_animationdata` (
  `anim_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `anim_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `loop` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weapon_state` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `freeze_start_time` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `blend_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '150',
  `play_speed` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `combination` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`anim_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=827 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The full file Base64-encoded (uncompress using `xz` after decoding it):

```
begin-base64 644 c_animationdata.tbl.xz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====
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. The uploaded file isn't even available anymore. So the question lacks not only context but also _the_ crucial piece of data that could be used to get some context. Please vote to reopen your own question once you provide the context or at least that file.

Comment: Given the `CREATE TABLE` statement this is in all likelihood a single table from some database in binary form. Very often a DBMS will keep a record of the statement that created a given table. In this case the `InnoDB` suggests that this is either taken from MariaDB or MySQL. It _does not_ seem to be a CSV file.

Comment: @0xC0000022L someone had shown me this, but I don't know how they were able to create this, probably their custom decompiler. You can probably make something out of it more than me. https://i.imgur.com/0rc1c9J.png

Comment: I'm fairly certain that not all of that data is contained in this single table. Instead, I would reckon, the data in this table contains references to other tables or even to data outside of the database (such as some list of strings) which can be used to assemble what your screenshot shows.

Comment: @ForChaos What is the source of this screenshot you just shared? What is the source of this tbl file and any related software that parses this file? Similar to 0xC0000022L I feel that not all data is present in this single file - any more relevant information would be great.

Comment: Is it from Heroes of Order & Chaos game? android or iOS?

Comment: @sudhackar, yes, as you can see from the file name from above. I was able to find a cpp source code an ftable parser, but it's very unorganized.

Comment: If you want to take a look at the source code, here it is: https://github.com/zhoulunhao/cxx_sth/tree/master/GCLDProject2/mysql_common

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited knowledge and references on strings I was able to extract some of the fields - most of which don't make sense like

```
Member(anim_id=1, anim_name=22821, name_len=4, loop=65536, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=2) bytearray(b'idle')
Member(anim_id=2, anim_name=22826, name_len=7, loop=65536, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=2) bytearray(b'idle_01')
Member(anim_id=3, anim_name=22834, name_len=7, loop=65536, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=2) bytearray(b'idle_02')
Member(anim_id=4, anim_name=22842, name_len=11, loop=0, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=2) bytearray(b'jumplandrun')
Member(anim_id=5, anim_name=22854, name_len=16, loop=0, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=0) bytearray(b'jumplandrun_left')
Member(anim_id=6, anim_name=22871, name_len=17, loop=0, weapon_state=0, freeze_start_time=9830400, blend_time=0, play_speed=1.875, combination=0) bytearray(b'jumplandrun_right')
```

- Field `anim_id` is a auto-incremented int represented as a `dword`.
- Field `anim_name` is the offset to a C-string in the file - represented as a `dword`. Its followed by a `dword` sized field for the length of the string which I called `name_len`
- `blend_time` and `weapon_state` are 0 for all fields. I could not see a default value of 150 in the binary file.

Similarly I guessed other fields as well - maybe someone with some time can handle and manage the code better.

The file header looks somewhat like this
[image: ida screenshot for header]
The header is followed by the query and then an array of dwords of values for the primary key field.
After which this is probably the field type specifier
[image: field tytpes]
where

- `u` - unsigned integer
- `s` - string
- `f` - float

The code to parse looked something like this

```
import struct
from typing import NamedTuple

struct_fmt = "<2Ii4IeI"
struct_len = struct.calcsize(struct_fmt)
struct_unpack = struct.Struct(struct_fmt).unpack_from
results = []

class Member(NamedTuple):
    anim_id: int
    anim_name: int
    name_len : int
    loop: int
    weapon_state : int
    freeze_start_time : int
    blend_time : int
    play_speed : int
    combination : int

mem = open("unk", "rb").read()
oldidx = 0x5925
def read_c_string(strtidx, anim_id):
    s = bytearray()
    strtidx+=2
    while True:
        c = mem[strtidx]
        if c == 0:
            break
        strtidx+=1
        s.append(c)
    return s

with open("unk", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(0xb53)
    while True:
        data = f.read(struct_len)
        if not data: break
        s = Member(*struct_unpack(data))
        s = s._replace(name_len = s.name_len % 0x10000)
        print(s, end=" ")
        print(read_c_string(s.anim_name, s.anim_id))
        if s.anim_id == 826:
            break
```

Comment: That is very interesting, all the others .tbl all have same offset, very consistent.